# How do you show non binding related errors on SpringMVC 3?

Tags: spring-mvc

How do you show non binding related errors on SpringMVC 3? For example, I want to show a message when a certain entity cannot be shown to a specific user on a GET method.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an object to bind to, you can have `BindingResult` or `Errors` in the method signature and use `errors.reject(msgKey)`

Comment: In this specific case, there is no entity.